# Restringir meu formulário para só receber arquivos .doc, .docx e .pdg

Tags: php, html

Tenho uma página e um formulário que recebe um arquivo no campo "File". Faço o envio desse arquivo para o servidor por meio de um código PHP.

Gostaria de restringir que esse campo "File" do formulário só receba arquivos do tipo .doc, .docx ou .pdf.

Vocês poderiam me indicar alguma solução para isso ?

Segue abaixo o meu código PHP que faz o envio do arquivo.

```html
<?php
 
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'portuguese-brazilian'); 
 
 //CRIANDO MENSAGEM DE ERRO -- NO CASO DE ERRO 


function enviarMensagem($dados)
{
 


 
 
  //ENVIANDO O FORMULÁRIO PARA O SERVIDOR DE EMAIL
  
    
   $nome_usuario = $_POST['nome-contato'];
   $cpf_usuario = $_POST['cpf-contato'];
   $email_usuario = $_POST['email-contato'];
   $data_usuario = $_POST['data-contato'];
   $telefone_usuario = $_POST['telefone-contato'];
   $celular_usuario = $_POST['celular-contato'];
   $interesse_usuario = $_POST['interesse-contato'];
   $salarial_usuario = $_POST['salarial-contato'];
   $uf_usuario = $_POST['uf-contato'];
   $cidade_usuario = $_POST['cidade-contato'];
   $unidade_usuario = $_POST['unidade-contato'];
   $mensagem_usuario = $_POST['mensagem-contato'];
   $cargo_usuario = "Estagiário";
   
   
   
   //Criar Variáveis de envio
   $destino = "teste@gmail.com";
   $remetente = "teste@teste.tech"; //Aqui tem que ser um email do próprio domínio. Email do site de hospedagem (Falta preencher)
   $assunto_format = "Trabalhe Conosco - DESPERTANDO TALENTOS"; //Pode ser qualquer mensagem
   $assunto = utf8_decode($assunto_format);
   
   //Montar o corpo da mensagem (Essa mensagem é a que chegará na caixa de email)
   
   
   $mensagem = "DESPERTANDO TALENTOS\n";
   $mensagem .= "Candidato: " . utf8_decode($nome_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "CPF: " . utf8_decode($cpf_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Email do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($email_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Data de Nascimento do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($data_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Telefone do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($telefone_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Celular do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($celular_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .=  utf8_decode("Área de Interesse do Candidato: ") . utf8_decode($interesse_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Cargo de Interesse do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($cargo_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= utf8_decode("Pretenção Salarial do Candidato: ") . utf8_decode($salarial_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Estado do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($uf_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Cidade do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($cidade_usuario) . "\n";
   $mensagem .= "Unidade do Candidato: " . utf8_decode($unidade_usuario) . "\n \n";
   $mensagem .= "Mensagem do Candidato: \n \n" . utf8_decode($mensagem_usuario);
   
   
   
   
   //Função está comentada pois ela só funcionará no servidor de hospedagem   return mail($destino, $assunto, $mensagem, $remetente);
   
   
   
   
   //Código de Envio do Arquivo anexado no formulário
   
   if( isset($_POST["enviar-contato"]) )
   {
    $nombre = $_POST["nome-contato"];
            
    $numero_erro = $_FILES['botao-upload']['error'];
    $mensagem_contato = $array_erro[$numero_erro];
    
    $arquivo_temporario = $_FILES['botao-upload']['tmp_name'];
    $arquivo = basename($nombre. " - " . $_FILES['botao-upload']['name'] . " - Estagio");
    $diretorio = "arquivos_curriculos";
    
    $novo_nome_arquivo = $_POST["nome-contato"];
      
    if(move_uploaded_file($arquivo_temporario, $diretorio."/".$arquivo))
    {
     $mensagem_contato = "Arquivo Enviado com Sucesso";   
    }
    else
    {
     $numero_erro = $_FILES['botao-upload']['error'];
     $mensagem_contato = $array_erro[$numero_erro];
     
    }
         
   }
   
  return mail($destino, $assunto, $mensagem, $remetente);

 }


?>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta, mas acredito que restringir no seu input o tipo de arquivo já resolve o seu problema. Para isso use o atributo `accept`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FRONTEND:

```html
<input type="file" accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx">
```

BACKEND:

```html
$file_info = pathinfo($_FILES['botao-upload']['tmp_name'])

$extencao = $file_info['extension']

$extencao_aceitas = Array('jpg','png');

if (in_array($extencao, $extencao_aceitas)){
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Essas soluções resolveram meu problema.